# Vector Theta gets unsigned after Gradient Descent

Tags: matlab, linear-regression, gradient-descent

What should I fix in the code below so that theta doesn't get unsigned? Theta is the vector that contains two zeros at the starting point. I'm trying to write linear regression and this is the Gradient Descent part of it.

```
function [theta, Js] = GradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, iterations)
    % Prepare Variables
    m = length(y);
    Js = zeros(iterations, 1);

    for i = 1 : iterations,
        h = X * theta;
        t1 = theta(1) - (alpha * (1 / m) * sum(h - y));
        t2 = theta(2) - (alpha * (1 / m) * sum((h - y) .* X(:, 2)));
        theta(1) = t1;
        theta(2) = t2;

        Js(i) = ComputeCost(X, y, theta);
    end
end
```

Comment: You can try subtracting 2*pi: `theta(theta > 0) = theta(theta > 0) - 2*pi;`. Theta is not going to get unsigned, but I don't know if the modified code works.